# Google App Engine FreeMarker template java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, freemarker

I am using FreeMarker with Google App-Engine Java.

`web.xml`

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>WebBookEditor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.business.cloud.servlets.WebBookEditor</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WebBookEditor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

template path: `/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/book_editor.ftlh`

code to load template

```
Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("/book_editor.ftlh”);
```

Configuration method

```
private static void instantiateConfiguration() throws IOException {
    if (null == cfg) {
        cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/templates"));
        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
    }
}
```

Will someone please help me identify what I am missing or doing wrong? I am getting the following exception

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/templates" "read")
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-047aec732318c54c(Request.java)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:484)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:698)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:877)
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$1.run(FileTemplateLoader.java:124)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:62)
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:122)
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:108)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(Configuration.java:314)
    at com.business.cloud.servlets.WebBookEditor.instantiateConfiguration(WebBookEditor.java:62)
    at com.business.cloud.servlets.WebBookEditor.doGet(WebBookEditor.java:33)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:310)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:302)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:443)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I haven't heard back from Google yet and I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209175/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-io-filepermission. So I tried the suggestions below but no luck. Is it possible that something is still missing in my `web.xml` or `webapp` path?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(classpath, '/'). 
Try following this link [Setting freemarker template from classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019424/setting-freemarker-template-from-classpath). This might work if you are placing the template file in a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means you have no read permission to `/templates`.

Actually your templates files are **not** under `/templates`, they exists in `getClass().getResource("/").getPath() + "templates"`. So the code should be:

```
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(getClass().getResource("/").getPath() + "templates"));
```

But I will suggest you use another method provided by Configuration:

```
cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(App.class, "/templates");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I find the solution to the problem at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11766. Evidently it's a known bug and Google is working to fix it. I hope it will fix my problem.